# If G is cyclic of Order 6...

Tags: abstract-algebra

An example in my Algebraic Structures textbook states that if

G is cyclic of order 6, that the only automorphisms of G,

$ aut G$ = {$ {1_G, \lambda} $} where $ \lambda(g) = g^{-1}$.

Now suppose $G=<a>$ i.e G is generated by $ a \in G$ and $order(a)=o(a)=6$ then
$o(\sigma(a))=o(a) = 6$ So that $\sigma(a) = a $ or $ \sigma(a) = a^5 = a^{-1}$. This is where I am confused why can $ \sigma(a) = a^5 = a^{-1}$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please check your question? I am afraid it is not clear enough (at least for me)

Comment: Note that $a^5a=a^6=1$, so $a^5=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that if you are given an automorphism, then you know that $o(a) = o(\sigma(a))$. Then, $\sigma$ can either map $a \to a$ or $\sigma$ maps $a \to a^{-1}$, since there are the only two elements of order $6$.

Now, you must show that this map, the map generated by $\sigma(a)=a^{-1}$, is an isomorphism from $G \to G$. So, just check it is injective, surjective, and a homomorphism.